# Where can I find On Balance Volume for bitcoin? (or ETH, LTC?)

Tags: ethereum, volume, prediction

I recently read about the usefulness of On balance Volume (OBV) in predicting price movement.

I use GDAX and don't think it has OBV. 
(Or is there?)

Any exchange that displays OBV?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No GDAX don't offer OBV.

However, you can use www.tradingview.com and apply OBV on chart from for example Coinbase/GDAX or other exchanges.

The sign-up is free, you only have to pay if you want to use more advanced technical analysis methods.

How it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

bitcoincharts.com
Symbol - itbit
Options - Show Volume Bar
Options - Volume in Currency

Better than nothing as my Chinese girlfriend says